# Android : Order of DialogFragments changing after Activity is resumed

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

In my activity, two DialogFragments are open.

Dialog1 and then Dialog2 above the Dialog1 (Both can be seen, one overlapping the other).

I open some other activity, and when I come back to my original activity through task manager, the order of the dialogs has changed..i.e. I now see Dialog1 over the Dialog2.

How can I maintain the order of the DialogFragments when I resume my activity from the TaskManager??

Comment: I get this problem too on pre-Honeycomb devices, but it reverses order when I rotate the device (I do not want to cheat with configChanges).

I would put it down to me NOT strictly following the DialogFragment newInstance way. After making a new project and strictly passing everything through setArguments(Bundle) it seemed to work!

Now I just need to backport those changes to my existing project, but I'm still getting the bug.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with the ordering of DialogFragments. In my case i had a dialog to set a time period and therefore it had to start also another dialog for picking dates. So after showing the second dialog and change the orientation of the screen, the order of two dialogs reversed, similar to your problem.

So, my solution was to create an FragmentActivity that looked like a dialog. I replaced it then with the first dialog. That way i could better manage saving instance state and stuff like that with Activity's lifecycle. This activity called then as usual the second dialog, without carrying something else.

My other Activity, that actually called the previous (first) dialog had then just to call the new Activity for result and that was it!

Here in more detail, how to make an activity to look like an dialog:

```
class MyDialogActivity extends FragmentActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog_layout);

    LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);

    setTitle("my dialogs title");
    setTheme(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL);
    // ...
}
```

I hope, it will help you, or at least give you an idea for a workaround for that ugly android bug! Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar trouble.
I created the first entity of DialogFragment.
Then I created the second one over the first.
The problem appeared when I rotated my phone. In this case the first DialogFragment relocated over the second.

It seems the issue is I created the first DialogFragment at the same place(method) where I dismiss another DialogFragment.

I did a sort of:

```
FirstDialogFragment a=FirstDialogFragment.newInstance(...);
a.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"");
anotherDialogFragment.dismiss();
    .....
// then somewhere in another method
SecondDialogFragment b=SecondDialogFragment.newInstance(...);
b.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"");
```

The issue was solved when I placed "anotherDialogFragment.dismiss()" before "FirstDialogFragment.newInstance()".